# string to byte[] array

Tags: c#, visual-studio

ok i know this has been beat to death but i can't seam to get all the ones on google here or anyplace to work

i have a string that looks like this

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

i store this string

each digit has a range from 0 to 254 and the string is almost random
i need to convert this to a byte array because of a hardware
change
this is what the hardware is looking for

```
hardware.command(DeviceID, byte[]);
```

i tested the  hardware by doing this

```
hardware.command(1, new byte[] { 0, 0, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38 });
```

and all was good

each part is a PWM output percentage on the hardware
this updates every 4ms so it has to be somewhat fast

Comment: If you're using .Net you'll have to add some 'real time' settings or Multi Media options if you need a guarenteed 4ms reaction time.

Comment: If you need to run fast, consider to work on byte stream instead of string. I mean try to get the input in bytes array form, using a buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
string datastring = "1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0";
byte[] data = datastring.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => byte.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

or, without LINQ:

```
    var datastring = "1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0";
    var tokens = datastring.Split(',');
    byte[] data = new byte[tokens.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++) {
        data[i] = byte.Parse(tokens[i]);
    }
```

Comment: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found

Comment: Ok, which framework version are you working on? Updated my answer to include an approach without Linq.

Comment: @TechMasterJoe: This means you are missing a reference to the LINQ assembly.

Comment: i have it but this app is OLD the idea was to just make do next time i post something i think i will just post large bits of code for detail just happy it works THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this satisfies your performance requirements, but the easiest way would be to use LINQ:

```
var myByteArray = (from s in myString.Split(',') select byte.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

EDIT: I originally wrote `byte.Parse(s.Trim())`, but [Byte.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0s9b1y3.aspx) does not mind surrounding whitespace.

Comment: Except that now you get the mapping `"1" => 1` whereas `"1" => 38` was requested (no idea what kind of encoding that might be …).

Comment: this is to much for a simple delimiter split

Comment: @Konrad string begins with 1,1,1,1 and mapping is not like you wrote. Byte array starts with 0,0

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Since the 1s and the 38s don't match `(1, 1, 1, ...)` vs. `(0, 0, 38, ...)`, I just figured these were unrelated example sequences.

Comment: @Reniuz, Heinzi: True, didn’t notice this. Well, weird example.

Comment: i can remove all white space from the string if it helps

Comment: @TechMasterJoe: Not necessary. "Does not mind" means that they are OK.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] substringArray = String.Split(',');
List<Bytes> listOfBytes = new List<Bytes>();
foreach(String substring in substringArray )
{
    substring = substring.Trim();
    listOfBytes.Add(Byte.Parse(substring));
}
Byte [] byteTable = listOfBytes.ToArray();
```

Comment: This will ignore malformed input (TryParse returns false) instead of throwing an exception. Thus, wrong data could be sent to the hardware device.

Comment: @Heinzi - yes, you have right, I had not thought about it. I already fixed code in my post. Thanks.